# How to "unformat" a numerical string? JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

So I know how to format a string or integer like `2000` to `2K`, but how do I reverse it?

I want to do something like:

```
var string = "$2K".replace("/* K with 000 and remove $ symbol in front of 2 */");
```

How do I start? I am not very good regular expressions, but I have been taking some more time out to learn them. If you can help, I certainly appreciate it. Is it possible to do the same thing for M for millions (adding 000000 at the end) or B for billions (adding 000000000 at the end)?

Comment: If you know how to replace, just replace `$` with nothing, `K` with `000`, `M` with `000000`, `B` with `000000000`...

Comment: I'm assuming you're doing this with SI notation format only, and the suffixes aren't localized to many different languages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var string = "$2K".replace(/\$(\d+)K/, "$1000");
```

will give output as

```
2000
```

Comment: Wow. This is exactly the kind of response I was looking for and it works beautifully. Thank you. I will mark your answer as right when SO lets me.

Comment: If and when hyper inflation arrives you may need : `+val.replace (/^\$(\d+)([KMBT])$/, function (_,v, m) { return +v + {K: '000', M: '000000', B: '000000000' , T: '000000000000'}[m]; });`   `

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to take a different approach to this, as the best way to do this is to change your app to not lose the original numeric information.  I recognize that this isn't always possible (for example, if you're scraping formatted values...), but it could be useful way to think about it for other users with similar question.

Instead of just storing the numeric values or the display values (and then trying to convert back to the numeric values later on), try to update your app to store both in the same object:

```
var value = {numeric: 2000, display: '2K'}
console.log(value.numeric); // 2000
console.log(value.display); // 2K
```

The example here is a bit simplified, but if you pass around your values like this, you don't need to convert back in the first place.  It also allows you to have your formatted values change based on locale, currency, or rounding, and you don't lose the precision of your original values.